Output text fields not working on wix using javascript
I am trying to take user input from dropdown boxes and text fields to carry out a calculation however I cannot seem to show the output in the boxes I want to.
Below is the code I have used to try and output the values but the boxes in the image attached don't seem to change:
 $w("#text5").text = (100 * (1 - Treatment1Year1)) >= 90 ? ">90%" : (100 * (1 - Treatment1Year1)) <= 10 ? "<10%" : (100 * (1 - Treatment1Year1)) + "%";

    $w("#text6").text = (100 * (1 - Treatment1Year3)) >= 90 ? ">90%" : (100 * (1 - Treatment1Year3)) <= 10 ? "<10%" : (100 * (1 - Treatment1Year3)) + "%";

    $w("#text7").text = (100 * (1 - Treatment2Year1)) >= 90 ? ">90%" : (100 * (1 - Treatment2Year1)) <= 10 ? "<10%" : (100 * (1 - Treatment2Year1)) + "%";

    $w("#text8").text = (100 * (1 - Treatment2Year3)) >= 90 ? ">90%" : (100 * (1 - Treatment2Year3)) <= 10 ? "<10%" : (100 * (1 - Treatment2Year3)) + "%";

enter image description here
I am new to javascript and wix so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Do you get any JavaScript errors?

A ternary is one thing, but chained ternaries are a mess. Are you sure that syntax is correct? Could that be reduced to a function that's easier to follow?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
